# How to make modal step by step in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I wrote a modal form in react using bootstrap and I want this modal to be in 2 steps

I also wrote the functions, but I don't know how to use it

```
  const [formStage, setFormStage] = useState(0)

  function nextStage(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    setFormStage(() => formStage + 1)
  }

  function previousStage(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    setFormStage(() => formStage - 1)
  }
```

When you click on next, the next modal will open and when you click on back, the previous modal will open

But I don't know how to do this using state

This is the first modal and I want it to go to the next modal when next is clicked:

```
    <>
      <div className="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Profile">
        button
      </div>

      <div class="modal fade" id="Profile" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title">Header</h5>

              <button
                type="button"
                class="close"
                data-dismiss="modal"
                aria-label="Close"
              >
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            <div>
              <form>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <div className="input-group mt-2">
                    <label for="recipient-name" className="input-label">
                      name
                    </label>
                    <input
                      name="myName"
                      type="text"
                      className="input-element"
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer justify-content-between">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                Close
              </button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" onClick={() => {}} >
                Next
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
```

the below form will replace the previous one , and replace the back button instead of the close button

```
              <form>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <div className="input-group mt-2">
                    <label for="recipient-name" className="input-label">
                      Family
                    </label>
                    <input
                      name="myFamily"
                      type="text"
                      className="input-element"
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer justify-content-between">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" onClick={() => {}}>
                Back
              </button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" onClick={() => {}} >
                submit
              </button>
            </div>
```

Comment: Checked in the playground and verify new code for to wrap the forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need a `switch/case` function to handle which form need to be rendered, based on the `formStage` state, and put this function into JSX.

You would also need to set the condition for your `nextStage()` and `previousStage()` functions, so the state won't in/decrease over its range.

If you want to display the title of the modal, like you asked in the comment, you could create an array of titles, and then iterate through it with `formStage` state in the JSX

I would suggest this structure for the code, you can fill in your JSX and CSS/Bootstrap classes. [Demo on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-night-dv15y?file=/src/Modal.jsx)

```js
import { useState } from "react";

export default function Modal() {
  const MAX_STAGE_FORM_INDEX = 1;
  const [formStage, setFormStage] = useState(0);
  // MODAL TITLE
  const modalTitle = ["Header", "Google"];

  function nextStage(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (formStage < MAX_STAGE_FORM_INDEX) {
      setFormStage(() => formStage + 1);
    }
  }

  function previousStage(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (formStage > 0) {
      setFormStage(() => formStage - 1);
    }
  }

  function handleRenderFormStage() {
    switch (formStage) {
      case 0:
        return <Form1 />;
      case 1:
        return <Form2 />;
      // ADD MORE FORM HERE
      default:
        return null;
    }
  }

  return (
    <form style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "column" }}>
      <h5 class="modal-title">{modalTitle[formStage]}</h5>
      {/* DYNAMIC CHANGING PART */}
      {handleRenderFormStage()}

      {/* NON-DYNAMIC CHANGING PART */}
      <button onClick={nextStage}>Next</button>
      <button onClick={previousStage}>Prev</button>
    </form>
  );
}

// UPDATE THE CONTENTS OF THE FORM HERE
function Form1() {
  return (
    <div>
      <p>Form1 Content</p>
    </div>
  );
}

function Form2() {
  return (
    <div>
      <span>Form2 Content</span>
      <p>Content for Form 2</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: When I enter a value in the first input and press next and back again, the value is empty

Comment: and how i can change `<h5 class="modal-title">Header</h5>` for every modal , i want to mpdal form2 will be `<h5 class="modal-title">Google</h5>`

Comment: I don't understand which "first input" you were referring to, could you clarify it? I updated the code for your 2nd question.

Answer (score 1):

For that, you need to add an if else condition during form rendering inside react.

I have checked complete single page app with full code to your solution and it will be:

```
<>
      <div className="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Profile">
        button
      </div>

      <div class="modal fade" id="Profile" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title">Header</h5>

              <button
                type="button"
                class="close"
                data-dismiss="modal"
                aria-label="Close"
              >
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
            </div>
            {formStage === 0 && (
              <div>
                <form>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <div className="input-group mt-2">
                      <label for="recipient-name" className="input-label">
                        name
                      </label>
                      <input
                        name="myName"
                        type="text"
                        className="input-element"
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            )}
            {formStage === 1 && (
              <div>
                <form>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <div className="input-group mt-2">
                      <label for="recipient-name" className="input-label">
                        Family
                      </label>
                      <input
                        name="myFamily"
                        type="text"
                        className="input-element"
                      />
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
            )}
            <div class="modal-footer justify-content-between">
              {formStage === 0 && (
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                  Close
                </button>
              )}
              {formStage === 1 && (
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" onClick={previousStage}>
                  Back
                </button>
              )}
              {formStage === 0 && (
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" onClick={nextStage}>
                  Next
                </button>
              )}
              {formStage === 1 && (
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-block btn-primary" onClick={() => {}} >
                  submit
                </button>
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
```